# Android email sending app

Tags: android, transport

I need to send an email with a photo but the functionality send doesn't work.It get stuck in:Transport.send(message); and go directly to catch.

Someone know why that is happening and provide some help or hint?

Below is my code which I tried till now

```
public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
    private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";
    private String user;
    private String password;
    private Session session;

    static {
        Security.addProvider(new JSSEProvider());
    }

    public GMailSender(String user, String password) {
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");// 587
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");

        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);
    }

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
    }

  public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body,
                                      String senderEmail, String recipients, String filePath,
                                      String logFilePath) throws Exception {
        boolean fileExists = new File(filePath).exists();
        if (fileExists) {

            String from = senderEmail;
            String to = recipients;
            String fileAttachment = filePath;

            // Define message
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(
                    to));
            message.setSubject(subject);

            // create the message part
            MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

            // fill message
            messageBodyPart.setText(body);

            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            // Part two is attachment
            messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            DataSource source = new FileDataSource(fileAttachment);
            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
            messageBodyPart.setFileName("screenShoot.jpg");
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            // part three for logs
            messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            DataSource sourceb = new FileDataSource(logFilePath);
            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(sourceb));
            messageBodyPart.setFileName("logs.txt");
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            // Put parts in message
            message.setContent(multipart);

            // Send the message
            Transport.send(message);
        } else {
            sendMail(subject, body, senderEmail, recipients);
        }
    }

    public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body,
                                      String senderEmail, String recipients, String fileAttachment)
    {

        File file= new File(fileAttachment);
        boolean fileExists =file.exists();
        try {
            if (fileExists) {

                String from = senderEmail;
                String to = recipients;


                // Define message
                MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
                message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(
                        to));
                message.setSubject(subject);

                // create the message part
                MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

                // fill message
                messageBodyPart.setText(body);

                Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
                multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

                // Part two is attachment
                messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                DataSource source = new FileDataSource(fileAttachment);
                messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
                messageBodyPart.setFileName("screenShoot.jpg");
                multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

                // Put parts in message
                message.setContent(multipart);

                // Send the message
                Transport.send(message);
            } else {
                sendMail(subject, body, senderEmail, recipients);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("error",e.getMessage());
        }
```